# Waiting for review queue suddenly nearly empty

Tags: support, review-queues

I am an active reviewer and check sometimes my statistics to see if my reviews are "correct" and go the way I think they have to go.

But yesterday I have noticed that my queue *Waiting for review* with over 100 entries is decreased to 7.
It seems like they are lost somewhere. My helpful flags, declined and disputed count didn't grow.

Is this a normal behavior f.e. there is a timeout while waiting?

Comment: Close flags are ageing away now ...

Comment: So my hours spending time in reviewing (100 posts) was waste of time ...

Comment: Yeah, if you look at it from that angle. You always run the risk that your close flag is not followed by 5 other members, specially in low traffic tags. But as you are close to getting 3K which enables close votes for you feel free to join the [SO Close Voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where we focus on specific tags which makes us as a group more [effective](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281074/how-effective-are-we-as-a-room). For close-flaggers it might help to leave a cv-pls comment in the chatroom.

Comment: What should be cv-pls comment mean?

Comment: See [this one for example](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21865198#21865198) which you create by typing `[tag:cv-pls] http://link/to/post`

Comment: Thanks, 20 votes per day is not much if you look how big the queue is.

Comment: You get 50 close votes and 40 reviews for the CVQ so it is less grimm ;)  I remember the days when the CVQ was over 150K...